# Am I messing with specificity ? What's going on?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I will short and clear. I have this html code snippet.

```
  <nav>
 <span class="heading"><a href="#">CodingHero</a></span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Home" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
   </nav>
```

Now I have this CSS part

```
nav ul li a {
        font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-size:20px;
        color:white;
        opacity:0.8;
        margin:0px 20px;
    }
```

This is also okay. But I found this weird behavior while dealing inside media queries.

```
nav ul a {
            font-size:44px;
            background-color:yellow;
            margin:0px;
        }
```

My background color works yellow fine.
But my font-size and margin doesn't work.
As soon as I provide specificity as I originally used in CSS part,

```
nav ul li a {
            font-size:44px;
            background-color:yellow;
            margin:0px;
        }
```

This works, my font-size and margin also comes into effect.
Can someone explain why I have to use the original selector that I first used to get all properties to act?
Why my font-size and margin were not applied when background color in same part is applied.
What's going on here? Any resources to clear my head.
Any response is appreciated.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-color:yellow;` was applied because the other selector with higher specificity (`nav ul li a)` doesn't contain a `background-color` property, so nothing overrides it.

---

If you were to add one like

```
nav ul li a {
    font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:white;
    opacity:0.8;
    margin:0px 20px;
    background-color: red; /* added */
}
```

then it'll override `background-color:yellow`, just like it override `margin` and `font-size`

Comment: @T J Yeah that makes sense for why my background was being applied when other not.       But what about the other question? Inside the media queries I used the  `nav ul a`  it didn't made any changes nor `a` and `nav a` , but only the same selector specificity that I used in first part of CSS `nav ul li a` made changes to be applied. Why other didn't made any affect. Do I have to used the same selector that I first used ? Help me to clear my head in this also or you can point resources.

Comment: @Biebk *"Inside the media queries I used the `nav ul a` **it didn't made any changes**"* - that is not what you said in the question. Maybe update the question or ask another question with working examples and ask specifically based on it. I think the answer explains what you mentioned in the question, and you're overcomplicating things in your head

Comment: If you are wondering why it works when you used the original selector, I thought you already know how it works because you are using the word *specificity* repeatedly in the question. The answer is *"**specificity***". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @T J Thank you so much ! I already know about little about specificity. But, what you said struck me suddenly and I got what I was messing with. Now, my own question sounds stupid to myself . But you spent time to help me figure that out. Thanks again.